# How to find route between two location in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, mkmapview

I know that it's pretty complicated in earlier version, is there any new way around in ios 5.Regarding this i can get locations by using Core locations GEOCoder, But wanted to draw the route between them, also iOS 5 has the ability to show alternate routes for a single destination from the source.

Hope Some One Help Me

**Note:**I'm using Map kit and core location not UIWebView with Google API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**My Problem :** Draw the route between two end location ( origin and destination ).
**Development needs:** iOS 5 sdk(which has the features to do so),Xcode 4.2.
**UI Design :** In my case it's very simple design. Two Input text fields and one button then MKMapView.
**Frameworks :** Map kit framework and Core Location frame work
**Development Steps :**

Get Two Input locations

Here i used the method `geocodeAddressString: completionHandler:` of Geo Coder class(from Core Location Framework) for getting the coordinates for the given location string(Available in iOS5)

Used MkPoint Annotation object for creating annotation on the locations in map

Then sent a request to the google API for getting the [Direction between two location](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)

As of the google API Response (Available in both JSON & XML) You would have **overview_polyline** object , which has the array of location coordinates. But they  were encoded, you have to use the correct decoding module to get the latitude and longitude.

with the decoded location coordinates you can create the poly lines using MKPolyline instance method.  `MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:[overlayPoints count]];
    [mapView addOverlay:polyLine];`

Now the polyline have been drawn over the map still it will not be visible

As the final go we have to override the **viewForOverlay** method for displaying the poly line view.

Hope this may be help full for you guys, if anything you may not understand then let me know.
**Cheers,
Arun**

Comment: Thank You @sanchitsingh. Your comment push me to write more.

Comment: iDroid,Can you share one sample please

Answer (score 1):

There is no route function in iOS 5 SDK.

So to make a route you need to parse data from route providers, such as [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) or use SDK from [CloudMade Maps](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects). Then you use MKPolyline to connect parsed points to show route on MKMapView.

Probably there are existing open-source projects with routes, try to search on [github.com](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=Objective-C&q=route&repo=&langOverride=&x=24&y=21&start_value=1).

Comment: I nod with you Flink if i using iOS4 sdk, But in the case iOS 5 Map Kit framework has more enhanced way of drawing poly lines by your own, and i figured out how to do that so. For detailed solution of my problem have been given as an answer, But still thanks for your suggestion.